# KDE 5.21 update is not available on apt in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: apt, 20.04, kubuntu, kde

I was using Ubuntu 20.04 and then I install and switched to KDE Plasma desktop. Now I'm using KDE 5.18.5 and I want to upgrade to the latest version (5.21), but there's no update on apt.

My question is: **How can I upgrade KDE Plasma to 5.21?**

[image]

Also I've added kubuntu ppa and its backport but no update after running `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade`

```
~  sudo apt-get upgrade 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why don't the Ubuntu repositories have the latest versions of software?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151283/why-dont-the-ubuntu-repositories-have-the-latest-versions-of-software), also see https://launchpad.net/~kubuntu-ppa/+archive/ubuntu/backports/+packages?field.name_filter=&field.status_filter=published&field.series_filter=focal

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @N0rbert I've added more detail and my question. Specifically, How can I upgrade KDE Plasma to 5.21?

Comment: @David I added more detail and question.

Comment: Plasma 5.21 is not available in that PPA, and cannot be installed this way. In case you want to use Plasma 5.21, you can upgrade to Ubuntu 21.04 (to be released in April 2021) instead. Alternatively, you can use [KDE Neon](https://neon.kde.org/), which is based on Ubuntu 20.04, but the KDE packages are updated to their latest version. Note that KDE Neon is not an official flavour of Ubuntu, and it is not  supported in this site. See the link posted by N0rbert to see why Ubuntu does not always update to the latest version of software.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade from this PPA: [https://launchpad.net/~savoury1/+archive/ubuntu/kde-5-80](https://launchpad.net/%7Esavoury1/+archive/ubuntu/kde-5-80) - Backport of KDE 5.80 stack (and dependencies) for Xenial, Bionic & Focal.

Comment: Is it safe? Have you tested that it does not break anything?

Comment: Not yet, going to. I tried 2 other PPAs of this author: `ffmpeg4` and `multimedia` - nothing broken, looks like very professional work.